# Automatically move camera A-frame js

Tags: aframe

I am creating flat tour using a-frame js . I wanted to move camera automatically.currently I am doing that using mouse .can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

To do tweening in A-Frame, you'll probably use the `a-animation` system:

```
  <a-entity camera position="0 1.6 0">
    <a-animation attribute="position"
            dur="2000"
            easing="linear"
            to="0 1.6 -10"></a-animation>
  </a-entity>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/donmccurdy/xr0pacxp/). To customize this, see the [animation documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/animations.html#component-properties).

> Aside: For VR scenes, moving the camera automatically is often uncomfortable for users, and should be done rarely and without acceleration, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

This along-path component is also good for interpolating an entity's position along a path: https://jsbin.com/dasefeh/edit?html,output